# How to fix margin between multiple radio when adding interactive elements between Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I try to add a so called `additional-options` element between the radios on my form, Bootstrap (BS3) causes different margins to be set on the radios. This is not unwanted, unless when hiding these additional options until the desired radio option has been selected (javascript interaction):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#additional-options-1").css("display", "block");
  $("input[type=radio][name=optionsRadios]").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "option1") {
      $("#additional-options-1").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("#additional-options-1").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.additional-options {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Try changing the following option and take a look at the margins of the available radios. What would be the supposed way to handle the margins? <br /><br />The radio element after the checkboxes requires a 'margin-top: -5px' according to the '.checkbox+.checkbox,
  .radio+.radio' CSS rule (by Bootstrap 3) but does not seem to get it after the 'additional-options' element gets a 'display: none;' (by provided javascript).
</p>
<hr />
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Radio option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="additional-options" id="additional-options-1">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Check option one
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Check option two
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<!--When additional-options is hidden:-->
<!--<div class="radio" style="margin-top: -5px;">-->
<!--Otherwise (no margin-top):-->
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Radio option two
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">
    Radio option three
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">
    Radio option four
  </label>
</div>
<div class="additional-options" id="additional-options-2">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Check option one
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Check option two
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<!--When additional-options is hidden:-->
<!--<div class="radio" style="margin-top: -5px;">-->
<!--Otherwise (no margin-top):-->
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="option2">
    radio option five
  </label>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daLzt921/)

As you can see in the example above, if the user selects any radio (but the first one), the margin betweem radios do not appear correct.

I tried setting in-line `margin-top: -5px` but this should also be removed again when concerning checkboxes are being shown. When the checkboxes are hidden, the `<div class="radio">` right below the concerning `<div class="additional-options" ... >` should have a `margin-top: -5px;`. How am I to solve this "margin problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customize bootstrap CSS like

```
.additional-options {
  display: none;
}
.additional-options + .radio{
   margin-top:-5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/h01wnqoz/2/

Comment: I would refrain from changing the Bootstrap CSS altogether. Changing Bootstrap would or could affect multiple other pages and above this, it might be a better idea to wrap concerning feature in an element and overwrite Bootstrap rather using given element. I will try and see if I can implement your solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

Different Margins are causing due to below Bootstrap Class.

```
.checkbox+.checkbox, .radio+.radio {
        margin-top: -5px;
      }
```

Override this class in your local CSS File as below and remove inline style "margin-top:-5px".

```
.checkbox+.checkbox, .radio+.radio {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
```

Comment: I know already that Bootstrap is causing this problem, I would not be mentioning the `margin-top: -5px` if I did not. I am looking for a way to handle/approach such a situation, not a simple override.